# German word for Seoulite?

Tags: single-word-request

Is there a German word for Seoulite, a citizen of Seoul, the capital of South Korea?

Seoulite is an English demonym and French has a similar word Séoulite, but I couldn't find a corresponding word in German.

- Cambridge dictionary EN --> DE for Seoulite: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english-german/?q=Seoulite
- Collins dictionary EN --> DE for Seoulite:
  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english-german?q=Seoulite

If there is no such word, what would be a good choice in terms of the general rule of word formation of German language?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The names for people from a certain city are made by adding *-er* to the name of the city. E.g.

- Wien — Wiener
- Berlin — Berliner
- Frankfurt — Frankfurter
- Hamburg — Hamburger

(Coincidentally, those are also the names of iconic snacks from those particular cities.)

So it's

- Seoul — Seouler

And there's an extra rule for cities whose names end in *-er* in the first place. Those get an additional *-aner* instead of a plain *-er.* E.g.

- Hannover — Hannoveraner
- Salzgitter — Salzgitteraner

No iconic snacks from those places.

The plural is the same as the singular.

Also, there's a female form for all those names. If you want to tell in particular it's a woman from that city rather than a man **or** a woman, add an additional *-in*. Or *-innen* for plural. Same as for occupations. E.g.

- Berlinerin, Berlinerinnen
- Hannoveranerin, Hannoveranerinnen
- Seoulerin, Seoulerinnen

And finally, the generic names are also good as adjectives.

- die Seouler Innenstadt — the inner city of Seoul

Please note those adjectives are special as they aren't declined and have caps.

Comment: *-aner* is not only used city names ending in *-er*, but also *-a*, *-i*, *-ien* and probably more. I'm sure Seoulaner would be easily understood, and similar would be Seoulese, Seoulenser, or even Seoulit.

Comment: Eine Person aus Tokyo ist ein Tokioter, aber eine Person aus Oslo ist ein Osloer. So, beware of exceptions to these rules.

Comment: There may be no iconic snack named "Hannoveraner", but there is a horse breed: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannoveraner_(Pferd)

Comment: @Bergi: Do you have an example ending on *-a*? The only one I can currently think of is "Jena", and somehow, "Jenaer" sounds more correct to me than "Jenaner".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I was thinking of *Fuld(er)aner*, though apparently [they don't know themselves what to call them](https://www.fuldaerzeitung.de/fulda/fuldaer-fuldarer-fulderaner-oder-fuldaraner-13726031.html) :-)

Answer (score 5):

> If there is no such word, what would be a good choice

Janka's answer explains there is such a word and how it is formed.
I would like to focus on the part *what would be a good choice*.

In practical use it depends very much on the context of your conversation, the city and last but not least the person you are talking to and their ability to see the relation.
It may lead to questions or irritations with an unknown city and also with cities that form a strange-sounding word.

Let me give examples that apply to me in particular.

- Münchner, Kölner, Leipziger, Düsseldorfer, New Yorker. I know the cities and don't know other meanings to these words, so it's quite clear what you mean.
- Berliner, Hamburger, Frankfurter relate to cities I know. The words are used for food too, but when talking about persons it's clear what you mean.
- Depending on the conversation I would know what you mean even if I don't know the city.
- Even for cities that I know and of course even more for cities unknown to me there may be words that sound odd and strange and I wouldn't get what you mean (while other people would - and vice versa).
  Then I'd wonder does it mean the person lives in city X, works at company X, is it a job title, a religion, does it describe a philosophy or any other characteristic of this person that I simply have never heard of?

To make it more complicated, it could be the other way too if I think it's a city but you actually mean something else that I don't know, such as a job title etc.

Now let me eventually get the connetion to your question and the particular case of **Seouler**.
While someone else might have heard this word more often, I am not so familiar with it and the context should be clear for me to understand that.

You could also use

- lives in Seoul
- is inhabitant of Seoul
- comes from Seoul